# I can't see Aptana Perspective in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aptana, perspective

I can't see Aptana perspective after install Aptana Studio 3 plug-in version in Eclipse 13.7 (Indigo). The plug-in is installed but i can't choose aptana perspective in Eclipse... When I'm installig Aptana Studio 2 everything is ok...

Answer (score 15):

In Studio 3, it's called **Web** perspective.

Comment: After installing Aptana Studio 3, I now have TWO "Web" perspectives; each with a different icon.  Once I selected the icon with the "X" in it, I was able to do Open With... JAVASCRIPT SOURCE EDITOR (as opposed to the Eclipse built-in JAVASCRIPT EDITOR).  Now, content assist seems to MOSTLY work.