# Eclipse doesn't give code completion suggestions with Javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, aptana3

I'm working with Javascript, and when I type something like "Math.", I don't get any suggestions, like "PI" or "random()".

I tried installing a plugging called Aptana but it didn't solve my problem.

The same problem happens when I try to initialize an object by a constructor function:

```
function Box(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var box = new Box(1, 2);
box. // nothing happens, even when I force it with CTRL + SPACE
```

Comment: Is is a regular project or a JS project?

Comment: Make sure you actually use the aptana perspective and aptana js editor.

Comment: Dynamic Web Project, inside a JavaScript Source File.

Comment: Why don't you use [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/)? It is an eclipse-based IDE for web development

Comment: @kapep How do I do that? I can't tell if I'm on that perspective already.

Comment: @wm1sr There should be an icon on the top right. Also see this answer and the comment, you might need to choose another editor when opening a js file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7788744/897024

Comment: @kapep Ok, I changed perspective to Web with the X in it, but it didn't solve my problem. But I notice one thing: The code that I posted above only works inside a function. If I try that outside a function or with the 'box' being declared as global, code completion doesn't work. Oh, and the built-in constructors still not giving code completion.